# Localization doesn't work on production - .NET core 3.1

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-localization

I'm using localization for my API application. The problem is, everything work well on local machine, but when I deployed the application on Azure, localization doesn't work anymore.

Here is the result when requesting on debugging (the message is translated):

```
{
  "status": "NotFound",
  "timestamp": "2021-05-05T03:31:10Z",
  "code": "R001",
  "message": "Customer order was not found!"
}
```

Here is the result when requesting on production (the message is dispalyed as key - R001, not translation value):

```
{
  "status": "NotFound",
  "timestamp": "2021-05-05T03:29:04Z",
  "code": "R001",
  "message": "R001"
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.

The prject hierarchy is as following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtqU9.png)

My CustomerOrder/Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    // Localization service
    services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
            .AddMvc()
            .AddViewLocalization(LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix)
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    // adding culture
    var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
    {
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("en-US")
    };

    var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
    {
        DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en"),
        // formatted numbers, dates, etc
        SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
        // UI strings that we have localized
        SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures,
    };
    app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);
}
```

How I use localization in my controller

```
...
private readonly IStringLocalizer<CustomerOrdersController> _localizer;
...
_localizer["R001"]
```

Task on azure-pipelines

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)/src/$(projectName)/$(projectName).csproj'
      arguments: '-c "$(buildConfiguration)" -f "netcoreapp3.1" -r "ubuntu.19.10-x64"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I manage to solve the problem myself.

It seems that the target namespace is incorrect when building the solution, so changing **Custom Tool NameSpace** property of the resource files (.resx) to **CustomerOrder** has solved the issue.

In VS 2019:

1. Right-click on .resx file, choose **Properties**.
2. Change the **Custom Tool NameSpace** property to the target project namespace (in my case **CustomerOrder** is the target project).

Or an easier way, add the below configuration to the .csproj file (the project that contains the resource files, in my case CustomerOrder.Api.csproj)

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Update="Resources\**">
    <CustomToolNamespace>CustomerOrder</CustomToolNamespace>
  </EmbeddedResource>
</ItemGroup>
```